# Changin admin email in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

So I am currently building a project with Django and will need to change the admin email to someone higher up in my division. However I am not sure who's email that will be as they are not sure yet either. If I put my email in now (as I will need to be using it when building the app), can I change it once it is ready to be delivered?

Comment: If your talking about Admin User or Admin SuperUser. Yes you can change email id after building the app. You can change it from django admin panel from User App. Even you can create multiple SuperUsers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of admin accounts you can make. When the time comes to transfer ownership, simply create a new super user and use it to delete the old one.

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```